# Почему при запуске exe файла AspNet Core проекта получаю 500 ошибку сервера?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Если запускаю с Visual Studio, то проект запускается.
Если же запускаю бинарник, то запускается файл, но сервер выдаёт ошибку 500.
Проект содержит стандартный MVC роутер, взятый из "коробки" майкрософта.
Если же запускаю стандартный HelloWorld, то бинарник запускается и всё работает.
Но при добавлении роутера что-то меняется и проект работает тогда только через открытую Visual Studio, а сам по себе перестаёт нормально работать.
В чём может быть дело?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

логи, если не включены в Startup классе, то включите их.
Добавить в метод Configure

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
```

и в appsettings.json

```
"Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Verbose",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
    }
```

Оказалось, он искал файлы Views в папке Views, а сам файл сидел в папке бинарников, где собственно не было папки представлений. Перенёс библиотеки и бинарник в корневую папку и заработало